# AngularJS ng-class parent menu active when submenu selected?

Tags: css, angularjs

I created Menu and Submenu this way:

```
<li>
    <a href="#/solution" ng-class="{ current: isActive('/solution') }" >
        <i class="halflings white home"></i> 
        {{menu.home}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Solution menu active when I on localhost/solution. How to do current parent menu when submenu was active? Something like:

```
current: isActive('/solution/1,/solution/2,/solution/3,/solution/.....').
```

My `isActive` method below:

```
$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
    var active = (viewLocation === $location.path());
    return active;
};
```

Comment: A regex comparison should work. Can you show your `isActive()` function's code

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, to check using a regex, use:

```
<li>
    <a href="#/solution" ng-class="{ current: isActive(/^\/solution/) }" >
        <i class="halflings white home"></i> 
            {{menu.home}}
    </a> 
</li>
```

You are passing a regexp to your `isActive` function which will match any string that starts with "/solution"

Now your `isActive` function has to test the url against the regexp:

```
$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
  return viewLocation.test($location.path());
};
```

for details on how it works checkout documentation on JS's [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [regex#test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)